# How to override list-type arguments that have default values

Tags: python, argparse

If there's an `ArgumentParser` defined like this:

```
parser.add_argument("--list", type=str, nargs="+", default=["arg"])
args = parser.parse_args()
```

the `list` type arguments can have their default values overridden by setting the argument to an empty string:

`python test.py --list ""`

and adding logic to filter `list` type args for `None`:

```
for arg, value in args._get_kwargs():
    if isinstance(value, list):
        setattr(args, arg, list(filter(None, value)))
```

Is there anyway to do this without accessing the private method of `argparse.Namespace`...ideally only changing what's passed from the command-line?

Comment: **never** use a list as a default value. Set the default to `None` and start the function with an explicit: `if default is None: default=["arg"]` . A list or other mutable object as default value will be reused (the _same_ list instance) in all function calls - if any values are added to it, this becomes cumulative with calls)

Comment: FWIW, in my case the CLI args are used to override the fields of Pydantic models which are initially populated from a YAML. All of these fields are effectively readonly beyond the CLI-override stage of execution.

Comment: @jsbueno, this isn't a function definition like `def foo(x, arg=['str']):`.  So your warning isn't applicable.  That said, the OP should show us what the `args` Namespace is after various inputs.   The `Namespace` class is a simple class.  `argparse` accesses it with just `getattr` and `setattr`.  You also convert it to a dict with `vars(args)`.  So you don't need to worry about "private" methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to create a custom [Action](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/argparse.html#action-classes) class:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse


class NonEmptyListElementAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string):
        values = values or []

        # Get the list of values
        dest = getattr(namespace, self.dest) or []

        # Add to the list only those none empty values
        dest.extend(filter(None, values))

        # Update the namespace
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, dest)


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--list", nargs="+", action=NonEmptyListElementAction)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Sample run:

```bash
$ python3 main.py --list one "" two --list "" three --list "" 
Namespace(list=['one', 'two', 'three'])
```

#### Notes

- The `namespace` argument to `__call__` specifies the namespace object
- In the action class, `self.dest` refers to the name which you can get/set within the namespace. In this case, `self.dest` is "list", taken after the `--list` part in `add_argument`
- The `parser` and `option_string` parameters are not use in this example
- `values` is a list of values from command line. It is `['one', '', 'two']` in the first call, `[''', 'three']` in the second call, and `['']` in the last call